# WPF - How to change Image in DataGrid column upon selection of row (in XAML)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Our project has a DataGrid that displays an image along with text in one of the columns. When a row is selected, since it's highlighted, the image is not visible correctly. Hence we want to change the image only for the selected row.
I know how to change the property such as background of the dataGridCell using `<Style.Triggers>;` but cannot figure out how to change Image that is embedded inside the  `<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>.` Can you please help me with this?

```
            <DataGrid Name="dgCPAGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CPAListDisplay, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="0,5,0,5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCPA, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" AlternatingRowBackground="White" 
                HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gray" >
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="DGCellMGA" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f8f8d2" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Right"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{b:CaptionBinding gridHeaderCPAName}" Width="Auto" MinWidth="125">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CPAName}" />
                                <Image Source="/Images/TimelineIconGreenTransparent.gif" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="15" Width="15" Visibility="{Binding StaticInd, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisConv}, ConverterParameter=inverse, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{b:CaptionBinding gridHeaderCPAMGA}" Binding="{Binding MgaY1P}" MinWidth="50" Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource DGCellMGA}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your cell's Template, add another Trigger (this time, a `DataTrigger`) that listens to the `IsSelected` property of the containing `DataGridRow`. Inside the `DataTrigger`, use the `TargetName` property of the `Setter` to tell it to modify the `Source` property of the `Image` (you have to give it an `x:Name` first):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CPAName}" />
        <Image x:Name="image" Source="/Images/TimelineIconGreenTransparent.gif" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="15" Width="15" Visibility="{Binding StaticInd, Converter={StaticResource BoolVisConv}, ConverterParameter=inverse, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="image"
                    Property="Source"
                    Value="/Images/Whateveryourotherimageisnamed.gif" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much @almuno